# Is a trajectory connecting two points valid for all the intermediate points too?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, boundary-conditions

Suppose a particle is described by a Lagrangian $\mathcal L(q_i, \dot{q_i}, t)$. Suppose that $q_i(t)$ is a trajectory (there might be more that one) along which the action integral is stationary for the paths connecting $(q_{i, 0}, t_0)$ and $(q_{i, 1}, t_1)$

Then, does the *same* path also make the action integral stationary for the paths connecting $(q_{i, 0}, t_0)$ to any *intermediate* point $(q_i, t)$?

---

My hunch is that in general the answer will be no. But if $\mathcal L$ is differentiable, then we'll have Euler-Lagrange equations, and this will make the answer to my question affirmative. But I'm not mathematically sure.

Comment: just a note: in case of  classical mechanics, the variational principle is supposed to lead to the same physics as newton force law, which in some vague sense says that "the position of a particle infinitesimal moment from now is determined solely by data observed now" and then you just add up these infinitesimal moments to get some finite evolution.

Comment: @Umaxo I don't think that Lagrangian mechanics is as general as Newton's laws. Though the Lagrangian formulation implies Newton's laws, I don't think that the converse is true.

Comment: yes, it is not. Sorry for bad wording, I was not thinking in both direction writing the comment. My point was only that due to physical considerations and widespreadness of variational principle in physics one would expect the "intermediate property" to be satisfied for physically meaningfull lagrangians.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the boundary conditions (BCs) of the variational problem are essential/[Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition)$^1$ BCs, and that the Lagrangian is sufficiently differentiable, then the EL eqs. remain the same for the truncated problem, say in the interval $[t_i,t_m]$. The truncated trajectory $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_m]}$ is still a solution to the EL eqs., so it will still be a stationary path for the truncated problem. (Here we are implicitly assuming that the intermediate Dirichlet BC lie on $\gamma$.)

--

$^1$ The truncation property (which OP asks about) does generically not hold for [Natural BCs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127) (because a natural BC is typically not satisfied at intermediate points).

Comment: Can you please give some insight on why the truncation property doesn't hold for natural BC's?

Comment: My main concern is with just essential BCs. Can you give an example (for essential boundary conditions) of some Lagrangian when this truncation property does not hold? I guess that this example must involve some non-differentiable Lagrangian (at least in some coordinate, at some point), right?